# Different template for items in ComboBox's drop-down list and for selected item

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a `ComboBox` with fairly complex template for individual items, which includes two images and several lines of text:

[image]

However, the selected item in the `ComboBox` itself doesn't display correctly, because the vertical space is too limited (I can't make it higher, because it is a part of a `ToolBar`).

**How can I make the ComboBox use a different template for the item which is displayed in the `ComboBox` itself?** (the default `ToString` representation would do just fine)

Thanks!

Comment: Is using DataTemplateSelector would do the trick for you or you are looking for an other soluion? Perhaps I do not get question right?

Comment: @sll I don't think DataTemplateSelector can do this (I didn't try it though), IIRC it is evaluated only when the items are being loaded. Anyways I would prefer some simpler solution that wouldn't involve a class for each ComboBox I create (there will be several of them).

Comment: Ok what are you trying to achieve? Different UI representation for items based on some criteria?

Comment: @sll As you can see on the picture, the item which is currently selected in the ComboBox is not displayed correctly. I just want to fix that.

Comment: How images are drawn? Is they loaded from file or somehow drawn using WPF facilities?

Comment: @s11 The images are generated on runtime and translated into a BitmapSource, which is then simply displayed using WPF's Image.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The selected item (in the `ComboBox` itself, not the dropdown) is not inside a `ComboBoxItem` so you can do something like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <!-- Complex default template -->
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding XPath=media:thumbnail/@url}" Width="100" Height="100" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Simple selection box template -->
                        <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}"
                                Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=title}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

(**Edit:** Note that the binding in the for the selection box will throw errors because the `RelativeSource` is not found. There are various options of circumventing this, one being a custom value converter that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the ancestor exists (manual tree walking).)

Comment: I wonder what WPF team were thinking when designing `ComboBox`.  What would be the *naive* approach to overcome this problem (when data template is used in 2 places: for list of items and for selected item when list is hidden)? `ContentControl` with styling seems a common [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191762/1997232) to deal with multiple templates (instead of crappy idea with `DataTemplateSelector`), but I really hate that checking for ancestor, which in turn also has issues as per latest edit.

Answer (score 11):

I was searching for a standard (not *hacky* and without binding errors) solution to this problem. And I found it [here](https://meleak.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/different-combobox-itemtemplate-for-dropdown/): using `DataTemplateSelector`.

It's the same idea as per [@H.B. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8279344/1997232): check whenever there is a `ComboBoxItem` as a parent in visual tree.

```cs
public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DropDownTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        while (container != null)
        {
            container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container);
            if (container is ComboBoxItem)
                return DropDownTemplate;
        }
        return SelectedTemplate;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ... simple template for selected item
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
        <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ... complex template used by dropdown items
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
    </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
```

Comment: Works great after selection. But on Init is SelectTemplate function not called.

Comment: @LWS, what is "on Init"? Why do you want it to be called on init and not when combobox decide? It may be worth to ask a question, I doubt to be able to help without [mcve].

Comment: When the Dialog is loaded. My ComboBox is empty. After first selection works everything fine. I just use your code without any modifications.