# Disable a subview depending viewmodel bool property (MVVM architecture)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view that contains multiple subview (UserControl).

```xml
    <StackPanel>
        <local:SubViewGPS/>
        <local:SubViewText/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This view binds to a ViewModel and I would like to load or not load subview depending on bool properties of my ViewModel

```cs
    private bool isGPSCompatible;
    public bool IsGPSCompatible {
        get { return isGPSCompatible; }
        set {
            if (isGPSCompatible != value) {
                isGPSCompatible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isTextCompatible;
    public bool IsTextCompatible {
        get { return isTextCompatible; }
        set {
            if (isTextCompatible != value) {
                isTextCompatible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

I actually don't want to "Disable" or change the "Visibility" but really avoid to load the component if the property is false. According this post: [Different views / data template based on member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190887/different-views-data-template-based-on-member-variable) the combination of DataTemplate and DataTrigger seems to be a way to reach the goal but I was wondering if it exist something simpler. Thanks for your help

I finally used this solution:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RLinkClient.LocationView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:client"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GPSLocationViewTemplate">
            <local:GPSControl/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="NoGPSViewTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="GPS Disabled" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" Opacity="0.1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NoGPSViewTemplate}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GPSCapable}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource GPSLocationViewTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but Frank answer is totally acceptable if I could change the ViewModel structure.

Comment: Why is toggling the Visibility a problem?

Comment: Hi Mike, it's just about optimisation. This View/ViewModel will be instanciated multiple times and I would like to limit the memory and CPU usage. Components used are pretty heavy and visibility property will just hide the subview but it will still be loaded in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using MVVM, you could create separate sub-viewmodels for the different views and add them to some ObservableCollection, depending on their properties:

```
<!-- This would replace your StackPanel -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Capabilities}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="localVm:GpsViewModel">
            <local:SubViewGPS />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="localVm:TextViewModel">
            <local:SubViewText />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

You would have an ObservableCollection in your view model, like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ICapability> Capabilities { get; private set; }
```

and add sub-viewmodels implementing `ICapability` to this as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the condition, I suggest adding the view object in code instead of XAML. Only instantiate when needed to avoid unnecessary initialization routines. That is, don't instantiate the view before checking the condition:

```
 if (IsGPSCompatible )
 myStackPanel.Children.Add((new SubViewGPSView()));

 if (IsTextCompatible )
 myStackPanel.Children.Add((new SubViewText()));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in this way I break all the rules of MVVM pattern (Sorry I just noticed I didn't precised this information in my post except in tags)

Comment: I understood what you meant but this ViewModel is not destinated to be used only for this specific view, I also use it for edit the configuration in another view. I just can't couple this ViewModel to a specific View (That why I would like to achieve this in full XAML)