# Use a different item controls in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a code like this:

```
    <ListBox Name="lstBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelsView}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlertViewOutput, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" >
                                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                                Value="{Binding AlertRecord.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <controls:AlertExpander 
                                                Margin="1" 
                                                Value="{Binding AlertRecord.AlertCategory}" 
                                                IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                IsActive="{Binding AlertRecord.IsActive, Mode=OneWay }"
                                                StartTime="{Binding AlertRecord.Timestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                StopTime="{Binding AlertRecord.EndTimestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                AlertId="{Binding AlertRecord.Id, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            <controls:AlertExpander.Content>
                                            <ContentPresenter>
                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                        </controls:AlertExpander.Content>
                                    </controls:AlertExpander>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AlertUnknownViewModel}">
        <local:AlertUnknownView></local:AlertUnknownView>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="4">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

`ListBox` uses my control `AlertExpander` as `ListBoxItem`.

Is it possible to create a list consisting not only of elements of type `AlertExpander`? I would like for an element of another type to also use the parameters on which `AlertExpander` depends.

I have several types of controls that accept the same parameters as `AlertExpander`, but look different, and I need to display elements of all types in the list, not just `AlertExpander`.

AlertExpander.xaml:

```
<Expander 
<Control.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- Header -->
                        <ToggleButton Name="HeaderButton">
                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=Expandable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"
                                                            CornerRadius="{Binding BorderCornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                    </Border>

                                                    <!-- Border shade -->
                                                    <Border Name="BorderShade" Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10">
                                                            <Image.OpacityMask>
                                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding SelectedItem.IconSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                                            </Image.OpacityMask>
                                                            <Image.Source>
                                                                <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{converters:GrayscaleImageSourceConverter}">
                                                                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}"/>
                                                                    <Binding Path="IsActive" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}"/>
                                                                </MultiBinding>
                                                            </Image.Source>
                                                        </Image>
                                                        <StackPanel x:Name="topHeader" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        <Label x:Name="bottomHeader" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" Padding="0,2,0,0" FontSize="9pt"
                                                               Content="{Binding AlertHeaderTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="BorderShade" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAlertHeaderTimeShown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="topHeader" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                        <Setter TargetName="topHeader" Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
                                                        <Setter TargetName="bottomHeader" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                    CornerRadius="{Binding BorderCornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={converters:AlertExpanderCornerRadiusTopConverter}}">
                                                                </Border>

                                                            <!-- Border shade -->
                                                            <Border Name="BorderShade" Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                                    Background="{Binding MouseOverShade, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                    CornerRadius="{Binding BorderCornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={converters:AlertExpanderCornerRadiusTopConverter}}">
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <Grid>
                                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10">
                                                                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding SelectedItem.IconSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                                                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                                        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{converters:GrayscaleImageSourceConverter}">
                                                                            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}"/>
                                                                            <Binding Path="IsActive" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}"/>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                                </Image>
                                                                <StackPanel x:Name="topHeader" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                                                    <Label Background="Transparent" Padding="0,0,0,2" FontSize="12pt"
                                                                           FontWeight="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Converter={converters:BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"
                                                                           Content="{Binding AlertHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                                        </Label>
                                                                    <Label Background="Transparent" Padding="4,0,0,2" FontSize="12pt"
                                                                           FontWeight="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Converter={converters:BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"
                                                                           Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Converter={converters:InactiveNoteVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                                           Content="{Binding InactiveNote, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                                    </Label>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                                <Label x:Name="bottomHeader" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" Padding="0,2,0,0" FontSize="9pt"
                                                                       Content="{Binding AlertHeaderTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}">
                                                                </Label>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="BorderShade" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAlertHeaderTimeShown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:AlertExpander}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="topHeader" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                                <Setter TargetName="topHeader" Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
                                                                <Setter TargetName="bottomHeader" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ScrollViewer Name="ContentScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                      Visibility="Visible">
                            <Border Name="ExpanderContentBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Control.Style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8cWC.png)

Comment: Define a `DataTemplate` per type in the `ItemsSource` instead of creating an `ItemContainerStyle`?

Answer (score 0):

Before I get to the code, I want to point out that this is a job for [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview), rather than control templates. 
The [`Template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.template) property takes a `ControlTemplate` and is used to define the structure of a control. This is usually used when you are building a control from scratch or significantly altering one. What *you* want to do is just change how your data is being displayed inside an existing control. For that, there are `DataTemplate` properties, such as [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate).

With that out of the way, I put together some code for you that should at least point you in the right direction:

```
<ListBox Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelsView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlertViewOutput, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:AlertRecord" x:Key="AlertExpanderItem">
            <controls:AlertExpander Margin="1" 
                                    Value="{Binding AlertCategory}" 
                                    IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsActive="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay }"
                                    StartTime="{Binding Timestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    StopTime="{Binding EndTimestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    AlertId="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="local:AlertRecord" x:Key="OtherControlItem">
            <controls:OtherControl Margin="1" 
                                   Value="{Binding AlertCategory}" 
                                   IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   IsActive="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay }"
                                   StartTime="{Binding Timestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   StopTime="{Binding EndTimestamp, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   AlertId="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OtherControlItem}"/>

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AlertExpanderItem}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

...

public class AlertRecord
{
    ...

    public bool HasPositiveValue { get { return Value >= 0 } }

    ...
}
```

I start by defining two different `ItemTemplate`s inside inside the `Resources` of the `ListBox`. You would define one for each of the different controls you need to use. Notice that I left off "`AlertRecord.`" from the bindings. That is because each `DataTemplate` instance will have the `AlertRecord` as its `DataContext`.

For the `ItemTemplate` property, I borrowed from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191762/5086631. I made a `DataTemplate` with a `ContentControl` and used the `Style` to change the `ContentTemplate` based on `DataTrigger`s. This lets you change the template based on the properties of your list item.

Based on your comment, the style is set up so that "`OtherControlItem`" (the non-expander control) is used by default, and `AlertExpanderItem` is used when `HasPositiveValue` returns true. `HasPositiveValue` is a property you would need to add to `AlertRecord`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

AlertRecord contains several parameters, one of which is crucial for selecting the desired control in the list.
ViewModelsView is the collection that contains the AlertRecord. 
I wanted to use different controls to display in a list.
That is, with the value AlertRecord.Value> = 0, it is assumed that the AlertExpander control (based on Expander) will be used, in other cases, another control (not based on Expander) that uses the same parameters as AlertExpander.

Comment: @DmitryAbt Okay, I've updated my answer based on that. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Keith Stein, thanks for the answer!
One more question - earlier I had such a section (see next comment) where the content for the expander was determined.
Where to place it now? Now, when expanding the expander, there is only a header.

Comment: <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AlertUnknownViewModel}">
                    <local:AlertUnknownView></local:AlertUnknownView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="4">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

Comment: @DmitryAbt What content is supposed to go into the expander? Could you maybe edit your original question to include a picture?

Comment: Keith Stein, I've updated my post (picture is linked too).

Comment: @DmitryAbt That should be defined as part of the `AlertExpander` control. What type of control does `AlertExpander` inherit from? (E.g. `Control`, `UserControl`, `ContentControl`, etc).

Comment: Keith Stein, I've updated my post (AlertExpander definition added).

Comment: @DmitryAbt You should set `AlertExpander.Content` to whatever content you want it to show (in your picture example it would be the string "Unknown Alert").

Comment: Keith Stein,
the content must contain a viewmodel that corresponds to AlertRecord.Value - there are several of these viewmodel, and they can contain not only text "Unknown Alert".

Comment: @DmitryAbt Right, from what I can tell from the `AlertExpander` template. Whatever you put in the `Content` property should be appearing in the Expander.