# How to show complex item description only if combobox is open WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am looking for a trick or solution on my problem. Maybe one of you may advice me some way ?

**STRUCTURE**

So I have my combobox with the code as below:

```
        <GridViewColumn Header="{lex:LocText CurrentWordCode}" controls:CustomColumnInfo.Name="CurrentWordCode">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ToolsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCurrentWord}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailbleWords}" DisplayMemberPath="Item1"  />

                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn Header="{lex:LocText CurrentWordName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedCurrentWord.Item2}" 
                        controls:CustomColumnInfo.Name="CurrentWordName"/>
```

Then SelectedCurrentWord is

```
    private Tuple<string,string, string> _SelectedCurrentWord;
    public Tuple<string,string, string> SelectedCurrentWord
    {
        get { return _SelectedCurrentWord; }
        set { _SelectedCurrentWord = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCurrentWord");
        }
    }
```

and I am creating objects of the above like this:

```
SelectedCurrentWord = new Tuple<string, string, string>(CurrentWordCode, CurrentWordName, CurrentWordCode + " - " + CurrentWordName)
```

And the ItemSource is like this:

```
AvailbleWords = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
```

**RIGHT NOW:**

[image]

Right now the first column at the image contain Code (first string in Tuple) and the second column contain Name (second string in Tuple). My problem is that user who is choosing item from combobox is not aware about what item is choosing because is seeing only the code, but not name of the item.

**PURPOSE**

[image]

My purpose is that in CurrentWordCode column user is seeing the code, and in CurrentWordName column user is seeing the name of this item. This is done for now. But when user would click on combox then I would like to show him items in format like this: "Code" + " - " + "Name", not like now is only displayed the Code.

For that reason I have created the third item in Tuple structure and there is "Code" + " - " + "Name" but the problem is that if item in combobox is choosed and combobox is opened then displayed selected item in combobox is also in this format, but there must be just a "Code".

Sorry for complex description, if it is not clear what I am looking for then please ask question and I would try describe it better. Thank in advace for any help. Regards and have a nice day.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279107/different-template-for-items-in-comboboxs-drop-down-list-and-for-selected-item). Can be easily solved with template selector. In addition you can *beautify* dropdown list items too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You can loose the third item in your tuple, this is purely for display puposes and should not be there, since we already have all info we need in the other two items.

Second, you will need to use a controltemplate to tell your combobox how to display it's contents. You will need two, actually. One for the selected item, and one for the dropdown. You can then use a datatemplate to make sure the combobox handles both cases.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExtendedTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="-" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TupleTemplate">
                <Control x:Name="theControl" Focusable="False" Template="{StaticResource ExtendedTemplate}" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SimpleTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ToolsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="200"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCurrentWord}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailbleWords}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TupleTemplate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you Bjorn. Code is running well. Really all good things for you !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the following properties of ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ToolsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCurrentWord}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailbleWords}" SelectedValuePath="Item1" SelectionBoxItemTemplate="{Path_to your template}"  />
```