# how to create some simple styling for SelectedItem of a wpf combobox?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a very simple WPF combobox as under:

```
<ComboBox  Width="192" Height="30"  Style="{StaticResource StyleCombobox1}" />
```

and i have defined the style for this combobox in App.xaml as under:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleCombobox1">
        <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source}" />
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
```

How do i set some font styling,background etc for the currently SelectedItem being displayed in Combobox?

Comment: Isn't that working?

Comment: My first approach would be to override a template and depending whether that item is selected change it's appearance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different template for items in ComboBox's drop-down list and for selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279107/different-template-for-items-in-comboboxs-drop-down-list-and-for-selected-item)

Comment: @JoshuaMiller Nop not a duplicate. In that case it gets all data from model. While here you need to know which item is selected.

Comment: @Karolis, your answer is almost an exact duplicate. In fact, if you replace `<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=title}" />` in the linked answer with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Yellow"/>`, and then remove the entire block that starts with `<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">`, it will have the same result.